# Ms access hangs up after left join

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm new to MS Access and database concepts. I have a linked table with 9500 records and another table with 72 records. In a query I used LEFT JOIN to combine both table which has common ID's. I did this to do DSUM. After joining my MS- ACCESS 2010 hangs up and loads very very slow. Here is my code for left join

SELECT column1, column2

FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID.

Can anyone help me to optimize this left outer join in MS ACCESS 2010.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Add indices to the join columns, if they are not already primary keys: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-0a8e2aa6-735c-4c3a-9dda-38c6c4f1a0ce

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for your comment. One table is from SharePoint and I can't edit it. Other table I can create index. But still it hangs up and loads very slow.